# Need 1 more 5v Pin - what to do?

Tags: gpio, power

First off I have only very basics of electronic understanding, so I welcome any help that I can get. I use a Touchscreen on my Pi that occupies all 5V and 3.3V pins. I also want to use a 433 transmitter module that needs a 5V pin, too.

What options do I have? Is it possible to use a 5V pin for two devices and if how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the wire.

You can power as many 5V devices as you want from the Pi, provided you don't use more current than is being supplied.  The current is typically limited by the 1 amp or 2 amp polyfuse at the microUSB socket.  The fuse fitted depends on the Pi model, those with a 40 pin expansion header will have a 2 amp fuse.

Comment: I have the Pi 2, so 2 amp should be all fine. Thank you, I did not know that this is possible. You mean something like putting a female male cable into the 5v power pin and then 'connecting' two devices onto the end of the cable? Or are there any specific electronic component for this?

Comment: There is no best way (that I am aware of).  It depends on what you are doing.  A breadboard will have a power and ground rail so you plug 5V into the power rail and ground into the ground rail and plug sensors into the rails.  You could use a female to female jumper as you say.  You could use a female to male and stick the male end into a terminal strip (so called chocolate block) and screw the other wires into the other terminal.  The possibilities are many and varied.

Comment: Ah, okay. As the module arrive I will update this thread with the solution I am going to use. I think a breadboard should be fine in the beginning. Tank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a [Raspberry Pi 7” Touchscreen Display](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156/l/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display) and a speaker that used two 5V and one 3.3V pins.

The installation guide above suggests powering the screen adapter board directly from the electric socket, then using a USB-microUSB cable to power the Raspberry Pi board from the touchscreen adapter.

The guide also mentions that you can power both separately, so you could use a plug multiplier to power all devices separately.

Extract [from guide](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156/l/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display):

> Connect a MicroUSB cable from the 'PWR OUT' port on the adapter to the
>   'PWR IN' MicroUSB port on the Raspberry Pi board. Then connect a 2Amp
>   external power supply to the 'PWR IN' port on the adapter board.
>
> Or
>
> Power both boards independently using separate 2Amp external power
>   suppliers connected to the 'PWR IN' ports on both the Raspberry Pi
>   board and the adapter board.